# Unable to send or receive files over bluetooth

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I cannot use bluetooth service on my laptop to send or receive files. All I get is this. Besides, I cannot even switch off the bluetooth from the bar on the top. Here is the screenshot. This state does not change and no device is recognized.[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy4MD.png)